# Wordpress option_tree overwriting

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 4.6.1 with the theme Goodlife.

Whenever I change the domain, my theme loses all settings (theme options).

Analyzing database, I realized that he loses the values changed in "option_tree" option.

To change domain, I use these queries:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'old_url','new_url');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'old_url','new_url');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value,'old_url','new_url');
```

I made a simple test to confirm, and copied the value of this option and enter directly into the database. Just that I load the wordpress that the value is lost again.

Now I have the "option_tree" value in a txt file, but the wrong value in the database, how can I use the real value in my website without it being overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing exactly how the data is structured, I'd bet 100% that the theme option corruption is due to the search and replace screwing up serialized data. Since serialized data defines the exact length of it's data, a search and replace (unless the before and after terms are exactly the same) can have the effect of corrupting all the data in the field. Most theme options are saved as serialized data.

Instead of trying to run your custom commands, I've found a LOT of success with this search and replace script meant for this exact purpose:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Follow the install instructions and run the search and replace through their tool. It correctly handles serialized data and prevents errors from occurring in the data.

Comment: It works! Analyzing the values of the serialized array, I realized that there were urls the logo for example (I thought he kept the id in these cases). Thanks